# Iterm2 disable Command shortcuts

Tags: macos, iterm

I use **Iterm2** on the Mac. Many times, I accidentally press <kbd>Command</kbd>+some key, so I'm wondering, is it possible to disable the Command shortcuts? Like <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for example, as I use *tmux* for split panes.

Comment: the most annoying of these accidents is ⌘+Q since Q is just next to Tab. The `ignore` shortcut below also works to disable this

Answer (score 47):

You'll want to override iTerm's default shortcuts with your own shortcuts to "Ignore".

Go to `Preferences > Keys` and press the + button at the bottom of the **Global Shortcut Keys**:

[image: Global Shortcut Keys]

Then add an entry for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and choose "Ignore" for the action:

[image: Entry for Cmd+K]

This disables <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: In my case I need to bubble the shortcut action up to the OS. Ignore seems actually stop it. Any solution for this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another useful option - you want to use Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V and Ctrl-Z in iTerm2, but you defined them globally on your Mac as Copy, Paste, Undo shortcuts.

To be able to use those shortcuts in iTerm2 to stop running command (ctrl-c), insert special character (ctrl-v) or put program into background (ctrl-z):

- create shortcuts ctrl-c ctrl-v ctrl-z in iTerm2 - **Preferences > Keys > +** same as in above solution
- instead of Ignore chose action "**Do Not Remap Modifiers**"

And now you can use ctrl-c for copy in rest of mac os and for break inside iTerm2.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to remap a key in iTerm2 to send an escape sequence. In your case, to remap <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to send <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, select the action *Send Escape Sequence* and provide the sequence of characters 
that should follow the Escape character to be sent to the terminal.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

You could just go to Preferences > Keys and manually delete every shortcut with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

Comment: Those commands are not listed

Comment: Please delete this answer. It is wrong and misleading.

Comment: @Behrang we don't delete wrong answers for that reason alone. Can you explain he harm here or better, why exactly this is wrong.

Comment: The `Preferences > Keys` panel does not contain an entry for Cmd+K so there's nothing to delete that can fix this issue.

Comment: Yes, the harm here is the possibility of a user wasting time trying to use this answer when, in fact, it cannot possibly work.