# How to disable iterm2 rectangular selection?

Tags: iterm

In MacOS iterm2
Option + Cmd: Make a rectangular selection.

how to disable this shortcut? many thanks!

Comment: This is not an iTerm setting. If you do the same on Apple Terminal.app you get a rectangular selection. This looks like it is a general MacOS Setting. But I don't know how to change it.

Comment: @Prado  yeah,, I want to disable this shortcut for Terminal.app either

Comment: This might help you. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85489/iterm2-disable-command-shortcuts

Comment: @Udhy thanks , but this can't solve my problem :(

Comment: @Prado This is not a general setting. It requires implementation in the project. https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3509